# Best practice - Check if Entity exist before presist

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Whats the best practice to check if entity fields exist before persisting it.
Here's the example
Entity

```
class Pile{
    /**
    * @var \ABC\CoreBundle\Entity\Record
    *
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Record")
    *
    */
    private $records;

    /**
    * @var \CSC\CoreBundle\Entity\Project
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project")
    *
    */
    private $project;

    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="Block", type="string", length=255)
    */
   private $block;

   /**
   * @var string
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="Type", type="string", length=255)
   */
   private $type;

}

class Record{
    /**
    * @var \CSC\CoreBundle\Entity\Pile
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pile")
    *
    */
    private $records;
}
```

There are two controllers that handle the CRUD of Pile and Records.
To create Pile there must not be any duplicate fields [project, block, type]

In Record Controllers I could create Pile together with Record.

Here's the problem where and when do I check the db if a similar Pile entity is created?
Whats the Best Practice?

1. Copy and paste the query checker in both controller?
2. Can I use $form->valid() to perform any check in PileType class?
3. Must I use a service and have both controller to call the service?
4. In entity life-cycle use pre-insert?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use a custom validation constraint in your form, so that `$form->isValid()` will do the check.
Follow this documentation entry on [**How to create a Custom Validation Constraint**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) to create the custom validator and then inject doctrine into it to do the check.

**UPDATE:** Well, I didn't know there was an [UniqueEntity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) Constraint already included in Symfony.

To inject doctrine do the following:

```
services:
    validator.unique.unique_pile:
        class: ABC\CoreBundle\Validator\Constraints\UniquePileValidator
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
        tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: unique_pile }
```

The validator class might then look like this:

```
// src/ABC/CoreBundle/Validator/Constraints/UniquePileValidator.php
namespace ABC\CoreBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class UniquePileValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    protected $em;

    function __construct($em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $repo = $this->em->getRepository('ABC\CoreBundle\Entity\Record');

        $duplicate_project = $repo->findByProject($value);
        $duplicate_block = $repo->findByBlock($value);
        $duplicate_type = $repo->findByType($value);

        if ($duplicate_project || $duplicate_block || $duplicate_type) {
            $this->context->addViolation(
                $constraint->message,
                array('%string%' => $value)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And to be complete, the constraint class:

```
// src/ABC/CoreBundle/Validator/Constraints/ContainsAlphanumeric.php
namespace ABC\CoreBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class ContainsAlphanumeric extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'This Pile already exists!';

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return 'unique_pile';
    }
}
```

Should be nearly copy/pasteable...

Answer (score 3):

Therefore, the fields must be unique?

If so, then it is very simple: [UniqueEntity](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html)

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
...

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"project", "block", "type"}
 * )
 */
class Pile{
    /**
    * @var \ABC\CoreBundle\Entity\Record
    *
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Record")
    *
    */
    private $records;

    /**
    * @var \CSC\CoreBundle\Entity\Project
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project")
    *
    */
    private $project;

    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="Block", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
    */
   private $block;

   /**
   * @var string
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="Type", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
   */
   private $type;

}
```